# Check state of FadeIn/Out

Tags: jquery

I currently have 2 buttons that make an overlay for the page toggle with a fade toggle function with jQuery. My problem is that if a user taps both buttons in sequence then the overlay appears with the first toggle fine, but then gets removed for the second, where it should actually still be on fadedIn

I don't know how to fix this:

```
$( ".navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(150);
});
```

And the second button:

```
$( "#searchToggle, #mobileSearchToggle" ).click(function() {
  $('.search-bar').toggleClass( "open" );
  $('body').toggleClass("noScroll");
  $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(150);
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup with a minimun example where the issue can be triggered?

Comment: Use fadeIn() instead of fadeToggle().

Comment: @SantuRoy But then it wouldn't disappear when the user tags the buttons again.

Comment: You can take a Boolean value for  first button you can set it true , for 2nd you can check it value first and change its value to false and use according to your need with if-else

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element is visible or not:

```
$(element).is(":visible"); 

// The same works with hidden
$(element).is(":hidden");
```